# magento getting the whole page instead of just variables value via controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

I expect the controller to return variable's value from **efund_2.phtml** when the ajax request is made via controller but its returning the initiator's(**efund.phtml**) entire html.

```
 /**
    * Called using AJAX POST method.
    */
    public function getEfundAction()
    {
        // Get post data.
        $PostData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $Param1 = $PostData['param1'];
        $Param2 = $PostData['param2'];

        $ModelLayout = new Pteb_System_Model_Layout_Backend();
        $ModelLayout->LoadLayout();
        $Block = $ModelLayout->SetContentBlock( 'efund-block', 'Pteb_System_Block_Cms' );
        $Block->setTemplate('adminpteb/efund/efund_2.phtml');

        // Passing parameters to template file.
        $Block->setData( 'MyPostData1', $Param1 );
        $Block->setData( 'MyPostData2', $Param2 );

        $ModelLayout->ShowLayout();//this getting the whole page html. But I just need the value returned by the variables in the page(efund_2.phtml).

    }
```

PHP function in efund.phtml page.

```
function GetEFund()
{
    var url='http://emall.3pteb.my/adminpteb/efund/getEfund';
    var DivResult=jQuery('#DivResult');

        var data = {
              "action": "test"
            };
            $.ajax({
              type:'GET',
              url:url,
              dataType: "html",
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                DivResult.append(data);
              }
            });

}
```

And the above function is initiated by :

```
$('a').bind('click', function(){
        GetEFund();
});
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

> In the network tab (Chrome console), I see the call is made to the
>   function getEfund(). However when clicked on it, it shows the entire
>   html of efund.phtml page , in fact that was what returned by the
>   controller. How can I make efund_2.phtml return its variables?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to set JSON headers in your controller:

```
        // Set our return json.
        $sJson = json_encode( $aDataArray, 1 );

        // Send it back to our ajax call.
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader( 'Content-type', 'application/json' );
        $this->getResponse()->setBody( $sJson );
```